# GPG decryption with regular expression

Tags: regex, encryption, gnupg

I am attempting to automate a process that moves a GPG-encrypted file from an FTP and decrypts it with GPG through Command line.

The file is encrypted on the sender's side, and the naming convention will be FILENAME_*YYYYMMDD*.csv.gpg. I can decrypt a specific file if I know the full name, but since the date changes I'm not sure how to handle that.

```
gpg --batch --passphrase EXAMPLE_PASSPHRASE --output "C:\Sender\FILENAME_20150327.csv.gpg.csv" --decrypt "C:\Sender\FILENAME_20150327.csv.gpg"
```

That works for today's file (FILENAME_20150327.csv.gpg), but when I try using * as a wildcard, ala

```
gpg --batch --passphrase EXAMPLE_PASSPHRASE --output "C:\Sender\FILENAME*.csv.gpg.csv" --decrypt "C:\Sender\FILENAME*.csv.gpg"
```

an error is thrown back with "gpg: handle plaintext failed: Invalid argument"

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Be aware that this is wildcard expansion and not a regular expression. The `*` in a regular expression has another meaning, and would match strings like `[...]FILENAMEEEEE.csv.gpg[...]` (with an arbitrary number of `E` characters, but nothing else allowed).

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround after reading http://parkingandyou.com/2013/02/08/wild-card-work-around-for-gpg-scripting-in-windows/. Instead of trying to use a wildcard directly in the script, I set it as a variable instead and passed it into the command.

```
SET FILETODECRYPT=

cd C:\Sender
for %%a in (FILENAME*.gpg) do set FILETODECRYPT=%%a

gpg --batch --passphrase EXAMPLE_PASSPHRASE --output "C:\Sender\%FILETODECRYPT%.csv" --decrypt "C:\Sender\%FILETODECRYPT%"
```

It's not the most elegant solution but it gets the job done. FILENAME_YYYYMMDD.csv.gpg ends up decrypted as FILENAME_YYYYMMDD.csv.gpg.csv, as desired.

Answer (score 1):

GnuPG does not perform wildcard expansion itself, and the Windows command line will not do if you put quotes around the path. Remove the quotes, so the command line expands to the full file name.

```
gpg --batch --passphrase EXAMPLE_PASSPHRASE --output C:\Sender\FILENAME*.csv.gpg.csv --decrypt C:\Sender\FILENAME*.csv.gpg
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately with the way the project was set up, I need the quotes since the Sender folder is actually two words with a space -- and that can't easily be changed now.

I did find a workaround. Will post my own answer in a minute.